# My AWS Elastic Beanstalk app disappeared

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was trying to view my elastic beanstalk apps after deploying through the AWS CLI and now my apps appear to be gone! It looks like they are still running, but the EC2 instances don't show up either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For some reason, my AWS Web Console region changed.

[image]

There's a dropdown in the top right. Just change this to the correct region where the apps were setup.